# Share contact, html-input type

Tags: html, forms, vcf-vcard

It is possible to share contact from my phone to html form (upload file), just like popular phone apps like whatsapp and etc do?

[image]

I really like how we upload images from phone, when we use `<input accpet="images/*" type="file">` - it opens phone's gallery once I hit the input[type="file"].

I wonder if there is a same feature exists that opens contacts book.

I know that there are contact-files with VCF format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard). But can figure out if it is possible to use the format in `accept` field of input.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you should use one of the next mime-types to provide users ability to upload VCards:

- text/x-vcard
- application/vcard (Macintosh only)
- text/anytext
- text/directory
- application/x-versit (Eudora Plug-in)
- text/x-versit (Eudora Plug-in)
- text/x-vcalendar

[Source.](https://filext.com/file-extension/VCF)

Regarding direct access to contacts from mobile, this feature has a *proposal* status. Repo is https://github.com/WICG/contact-api. You can play with the feature here https://whatwebcando.today/contacts.html.

Hope these help!